# Using Hardware Performance Counters in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, multicore

I want to use the Hardware Performance Counters that come with the Intel and AMD x86_64 multicore processors to calculate the number of retired stores by a program. I want each thread to calculate its retired stores separately. Can it be done? And if so, how in C/C++?

Comment: Is this task so difficult to perform that no one knows about it :(!

Comment: Have you ever heard about PAPI (Performance Application Programming Interface)? I've worked with it under intel x86. I'm not sure if it has AMD support, but here's a pdf with some info ww.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/papi-linux.pdf. Is this what you want?

Comment: Fred, is it freely available? If so, from where can I download it?

Comment: I think you can get it from http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/software/index.html - but I'm not sure how to set it up. I used it in a server with everything ready to be used. It may involve kernel patching :\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Perfctr or PAPI if you want to count hardware events on some part of the program internally (without starting any 3rd party tool).

Perfctr quickstart: http://www.ale.csce.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~satoshi/how_to_use_perfctr.htm

PAPI homepage: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/

PerfSuite good doc: http://perfsuite.ncsa.illinois.edu/publications/LJ135/x27.html

If you can do this externally, there is a `perf` command of modern Linux.

perf wiki: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Good to know about the `perf` command. I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach will be using perf in linux as osgx mentioned, as it is part of linux kernel. But it CAN be called in the C/C++ code as well, and there is no need for it to be external perf stat calls.

Just download the kernel source code and take a look at it. Or alternatively take a look at this library I think by google:

http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/docs_v4.html

it is part of perfmon2 project but is designed to work with perf. Take a look at perf_examples directory and you will get the idea. That is how I handle perf calls from within my C codes.

Comment: Hi Saman! Can you please share a simple example of executing a binary from within a program and counting say the "retired Instructions", and writing them into a file? 

I tried hard to understand the examples, but either I'm too dumb or the examples are too vague. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: so an example would be:
[code]
int main(){
fork child(){
   execv(binary)
}
count retired instructions()
write to a file()
End
}

Answer (score 2):

The official application from AMD is named [CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools/CodeAnalyst/Pages/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Checked out `oprofile` yet?

http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Please expand this answer. You're correct, but there is too little information for those who don't already understand how OProfile works.